# How to capture ambient Networks in android

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am capturing the current network by using telephony service.

```
int networkType = mTelephonyManager.getNetworkType();
        if(networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN){
            Log.e("", "Connectivity telephone network exists"); 
            String networkCode = mTelephonyManager.getNetworkOperator();
            String networkName = mTelephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
}
```

But after this I also want to capture the ambient or other available networks.

How can I achieve this ?

Adding more information about this.
In your android device, Settings-More-Wireless & networks- mobile Networks-Network Operators
This is under available network heading.
I want to know about this.
how can my app capture this information.